# [spring-kafka]: Edit log.retention.bytes after kafka topic is created

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

We are using Debezium + spring-boot + spring-kafka in our java app. Debezium code will automatically create a few kafka topics. Is it possible to modify those topics' properties using spring-kafka?

Can we set some property in application.properties OR modify debezium configuration to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean the `retention.bytes` topic property; `log.retention.bytes` is a broker property.

The issue I previously reported [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2832) was with a typo in the config name; the following should always work.

```
spring.kafka.admin.modify-topic-configs=true
```

```java
@Bean
ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaAdmin admin) {
    return args -> {
        admin.createOrModifyTopics(TopicBuilder.name("topic1")
                .config("retention.bytes", "100000")
                .partitions(1)
                .replicas(1)
                .build());
    };
}
```

You can also just declare it as a bean and the framework will make the call for you:

```java
@Bean
NewTopic topic() {
    return TopicBuilder.name("topic1")
            .config("retention.bytes", "200000")
            .partitions(1)
            .replicas(1)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: The issue I previously reported was with a typo in the config name; the suggested code should always work.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell. Which issue did you previously report?

Comment: I can wait for the 'fix' but which fix are you referring to?

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the issue; turned out it wasn't a bug the way I originally described; just an NPE if you mis-spelled a topic property name (which I did in my original test). https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2832 No need to wait for the fix.